# Is there such a thing as a non-trash open (free) API or "regular data dump"?

Tags: data-request, api, uses-of-open-data

I'm desperate to find something to make me money. For this reason, I've recently gone through huge lists of APIs available, and it seems as if 100% of the ones that don't charge you money are extremely low quality. For example, some API (also offering a data dump, which I studied) which was supposed to give area names and street names for many countries, lacked my street for my country. Incomplete, buggy and useless for relying on.

The other problem is that all of these free APIs that exist seem to do very pointless things, such as dispense a stupid joke or something. I want things like up-to-date, official information about a given address such as who lives there, etc.

Just about anything I would need or find useful in the least wants me to pay them money, which I don't have. I also have no desire to reveal my identity for any more companies with constant data leaks everywhere, so that's also a huge problem even besides the sheer monetary cost.

It really appears as if all worthwhile data is securely locked away behind thick paywalls with huge padlocks.

I'm trying to come up with some kind of system which fetches data from various free APIs (or possibly paid ones, if it turns out to be worth it), process it locally with some "patented logic" (the real work), and then publish it in a new form which is very valuable to somebody so that they will give me money for it.

You keep hearing about all this data that is allegedly available, but I don't see how I'm going to get hold of it since I'm not already rich.

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention what kind of data you're looking for. For now your question looks more like a rant.

Comment: to be clear, you are asking for open data solutions so that you can leverage them for profit? and asking in an open data forum, nonetheless. moreover, this is incredibly vague, it seems like there is no product/end point whatsoever, it goes from data utility -> profit. this may sound critical, but i am trying to understand what you are asking. this seems to not fit this forum's model at all.

Comment: I don’t see a question?